# How to configure maps in MR jobs to execute in batches?

Tags: hadoop, hive, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn, cloudera

Map-reduce job spawns several mappers and running in Yarn. How to run those mappers in batches . Say if the MR job spawned 100 Maps, how to run only 10 at a time and how to configure next 10 mappers to be picked up once the previous set is complete. 
Currently all the mapper are running in parallel.

Comment: You probably use the _Fair Scheduler_ (cf. Cloudera tag) > bribe an Admin to create a specific YARN queue for you, with "max resources" just large enough to hold 10 mappers + 1 AppMaster; then run your job on that specific queue. Cf. https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.4/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/FairScheduler.html and https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.4/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/mapred-default.xml under `mapreduce.job.queuename`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Hadoop 2.7 or newer, you can use 
`mapreduce.job.running.map.limit`
property to limit the number of mappers running simultaneously